# Solve $ (13+x)^{1/4}+(4-x)^{1/4}=3$

Tags: polynomials, radicals

> I have to find all the solution of the equation $ (13+x)^{1/4}+(4-x)^{1/4}=3$.

I know the real solution is $-12$ and $3$ but I don't know how to find them.

Comment: Have you tried many time squaring?

Comment: This looks like a horrible exercise of many times squaring. I'd wish there's some nice trick there and I expect a nice answer.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN. Would you try ? Not me !!

Comment: You can make the monster looking nicer using $x=y-\frac 92$ to get $$\sqrt[4]{\frac{17}{2}-y}+\sqrt[4]{y+\frac{17}{2}}=3$$ I suppose that the symmetry has to play a role here.

Comment: A standard procedure is to consider $$u=\sqrt[4]{13+x}\qquad v=\sqrt[4]{4-x}$$ and to look for $$s=u+v\qquad p=uv.$$ One knows that $$s^4=u^4+v^4+4uv(u^2+v^2)+6u^2v^2=u^4+v^4+4ps^2-2p^2$$ and one is given that $$u^4+v^4=17\qquad s=3,$$ hence $$2p^2-36p+64=0,$$ that is, $p=9\pm7$. Now, $u$ and $v$ solve $t^2-st+p=0$, that is, $$t^2-3t+9\pm7=0,$$ hence $$t^2-3t+2=0$$ (to have some real roots), hence $u,v=1,2$. Now $x=u^4-13$ hence $$x=-12\quad\text{or}\quad x=3.$$

Comment: The comment above answers the "how to find the real solutions" part. If the question was "how to find all the solutions" one should turn to the discarded case $p=9+7=16$, that is, $t^2-3t+16=0$.

Answer (score 1):

setting $$a=\sqrt[4]{13+x}$$ and $$b=\sqrt[4]{4-x}$$ we get the system $$a^4+b^4=17$$ and $$a+b=3$$ with $$b=3-a$$ we get the equation $$a^4+(3-a)^4=17$$
it is $$2(-2+a)(a-1)(16-3a+a^2)=0$$ solve this equation

Comment: And what next ? A cubic in $a$ which is ugly !

Comment: This is wrong starting at $a^4-b^4=9$.

Comment: $a^4-b^4\ne 9$.

Comment: i have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting

$$a=4-x$$

and

$$b=13+x$$

we have :

$$a^{1/4}+b^{1/4}=3$$

Solving by

$$b=( 3-a^{1/4})^{4}$$

but

$$b=17-a$$,

therefore

$$17-a= (3-a^{1/4})^{4}$$

This equation has as roots $a=1$ and $a=16$, hence $x=3$ and $x=-12$.